# MySQL - row number in recordset?

Tags: mysql

First of all, I'm not asking how to get the current row number after the results have been return to you.

I'm wondering, is it possible to get the row number as one of the returned columns in MySQL results? What I'm trying to do is to add a number to increments up to every single row. Like this:

```
| id | myNum | name |
+----+-------+------+
| 34 |     1 | John |
| 24 |     2 | Alex |
| 56 |     3 | Brad |
etc...
```

I'm guessing it would involve stored procedures, but I'm wondering if it's possible without them...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select table.*,@rn:=@rn+1 as row_num
from table,(select @rn:=0) as r order by field_you_like
```

Comment: Ah brilliant! You don't have to declare the variable ahead of time or anything like that?

Comment: @Jakobud: No, it's not necessary. You can initialize it within the same query. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
select @n := @n + 1 mynum, t.*
from (select @n:=0) initvars, tbl t
```

Comment: Did you mean `select @n := @n + 1 AS mynum` instead of `select @n := @n + 1 mynum` without the `AS`? If not, why should that work???

Comment: @smhnaji: The `AS` is optional when specifying what to `SELECT` or what table to select `FROM`: `SELECT t.num number FROM table t` is a valid query.