# mysql row number implementation that is always incremental (sorted from 1 to n)

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, row

My previous search results (containing [MySQL - row number in recordset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285660/mysql-row-number-in-recordset) that really helped me) was not satisfying because sorting by other columns overrides the native sort of `@RowNumber`.

Consider my simplified `member` table below:

```
row_number | id | firstname | lastname
--------------------------------------
1          | 1  | Steve     | Jobs
2          | 2  | Bill      | Gates
3          | 3  | Rasmus    | Lerdorf
4          | 4  | Linus     | Torvalds
```

resulted by the following query:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1 AS row_number
FROM member, (SELECT @RowNumber := 0) AS counter_table
```

But when I'm going to sort based on some columns other than row_number or id, the `row_number`'s sort will corrupt:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1 AS row_number
FROM member, (SELECT @RowNumber := 0) AS counter_table
ORDER BY firstname DESC
```

Result:

```
row_number | id | firstname | lastname
--------------------------------------
2          | 2  | Bill      | Gates
4          | 4  | Linus     | Torvalds
3          | 3  | Rasmus    | Lerdorf
1          | 1  | Steve     | Jobs
```

Note: None of the table, queries and any other thing are tested examples. Only the problem itself is in the real world!

I supposed those simple situations to be easy to understand and resolve. (If they were any problem, please forget about those little mistakes and consider the important problem itself)

Comment: Of course it will "corrupt". There's no rule saying what the row's number is in the record set because the results are created dynamically, yet you have a column denoting the number of the row. This is why people usually do this functionality in application rather than db.

Comment: rownumber isn't a static column in the table so any sorts on column will always take precedence.  You could try creating a view that has rownumber as one of the columns and then run your query against that view.

Comment: That's because `ORDER` is occurring after `SELECT`. If you add an index on firstname, the results would be returned in order, instead of being ordered later, so it would work. It still smells though.

Comment: Thank you for both of you. So the only *easy* way that remains, is php side row_number. Please post your negative answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Dear @MarcusAdams; Thank you for your comment. Would you please clarify me with a piece of code? Does it look an easy way?

Comment: The problem is that I'm asking user to select each columns that he wants and he's also able to sort the results by any selected columns. Beside any real column in the table(s), the user wants to see the # of each column as well. Is @MarcusAdams's solution implementable in this situation that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation on row_number is dependent of the results being returned from the database already in the order in which you are displaying them.

The reason that it fails when you order by firstname is because the results are being returned from the database in order of the primary key, so id 1 get row_number 1, then they're ordered via firstname later (via filesort).

If you add an index on the firstname column, then the results will be fetched from the database ordered by firstname instead of the primary key, so the row numbers will be fine.

If you do an `EXPLAIN` on your query you will notice that it's probably using the primary key as the index, and using filesort to order the results because it doesn't have an index on firstname. The order occurs after the results are fetched from the table.

Adding an index on firstname, you'll see that it will use the index on firstname to fetch the results from the database already ordered by firstname, so the first name will have row_number 1.

To play it safe, you'll probably want to force the index.

However, this is strictly academic to explain what's occurring and how you might work around the issue.

The most likely solution would be to perform your first query as a subquery, and add the row number in an outer query, after the results have already been ordered.
Some applications will reissue a query any time the user wants to change the sort order, however, some applications will cache the results, order them in the application, and generate the row numbers in the application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explaination. So I got that in my case that user might want to sort by each of the columns, the PHP side way looks more safe (and easier of course :D).

Answer (score 2):

That should be obvious: number rows first, order them later.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, firstname, lastname, @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1 AS row_number
  FROM member, (SELECT @RowNumber := 0) AS counter_table
) AS sq
ORDER BY firstname DESC
```

oh wait... you actually want the other way round, order first, number later:

```
SELECT sq.*, @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1 AS row_number FROM (
  SELECT id, firstname, lastname
  FROM member
  ORDER BY firstname DESC
) AS sq
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RowNumber := 0) AS counter_table
```

Comment: It's not 100% implementable by CodeIgniter's Active Record! I think that I should go for PHP side row_number. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If your original solution was implementable in CI, so should this one. It does not introduce any new syntax. Just guessing here though, I've no knowledge of CI

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I know that I hadn't mentioned that I'm a CI guy. As I some where read, unfortunately sub-queries ARE in fact implementable, but with some tricks. Anyway your solution looks to me so expert! I should though appreciate your help. +1