# MySQL return first n rows and group the rest

Tags: mysql, group-by

I wnat to draw a pie chart with MySQL data. I need to retrieve the first n rows and group the rest.
The problem is that the first query is already grouped.

```
SELECT name AS especie, SUM(superficie) AS superficie
FROM ciclos
JOIN cultivos ON id_cultivo = idcultivo
JOIN tbl_especies ON id_especie = idespecie
WHERE fecha_cierre IS NULL
GROUP BY id_especie
ORDER BY superficie DESC
```

This is what I get:

```
+------------+------------+
|  Especie   | Superficie |
+------------+------------+
| Avena      | 50.0000    |
| Centeno    | 32.4000    |
| Trigo      | 18.0000    |
| Almendros  | 5.1100     |
| Olivos     | 4.7000     |
| Vid        | 1.8300     |
| Nogal      | 0.3500     |
| Cerezo     | 0.2500     |
+------------+------------+
```

And this is what I need:

```
+------------+------------+
|  Especie   | Superficie |
+------------+------------+
| Avena      | 50.0000    |
| Centeno    | 32.4000    |
| Trigo      | 18.0000    |
| Almendros  | 5.1100     |
| Rest       | 7.1300     |
+------------+------------+
```

In this case, I need to retrieve the first 4 rows and group the rest.

Is there any way to solve this with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I took the @Gordon Linoff concept and mixed it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9466744/1095101).
The problem with the @Gordon Linoff solution, was that the row number were added during the order.

```
SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn, SUM(superficie) AS superficie, (CASE WHEN @rn <= 4 THEN name ELSE "Other" END) AS especie
FROM (
    SELECT name, SUM(superficie) AS superficie
    FROM ciclos
    JOIN cultivos ON id_cultivo = idcultivo
    JOIN tbl_especies ON id_especie = idespecie
    WHERE fecha_cierre IS NULL
    GROUP BY id_especie
    ORDER BY superficie DESC
) AS temp
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS const
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN @rn <= 4 THEN name ELSE "Other" END)
ORDER BY superficie DESC
```

Hope this helps someone. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one query, but it requires a subquery (in the end, somehow, you have to group already grouped data).  Here is one, MySQL-specific way.  It adds a sequence number on the rows using a variable, and then uses that for the grouping:

```
select (case when rn <= 4 then especie else 'otros' end) as grouping,
       sum(superficie) as superficie
from (SELECT name AS especie, SUM(superficie) AS superficie, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      FROM ciclos
      JOIN cultivos ON id_cultivo = idcultivo
      JOIN tbl_especies ON id_especie = idespecie
      cross join (select @rn := 0) const
      WHERE fecha_cierre IS NULL
      GROUP BY id_especie
      ORDER BY superficie DESC
     ) t
group by (case when rn <= 4 then especie else 'otros' end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the query but is throwing me a syntax error near: "@rn := 0) const WHERE..." and I don't know why.

Comment: Fixed, "SELECT" was missing inside CROSS JOIN: CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) const. Now, the problem is that I get the first 4 rows but they are not order by "superficie". Actually, what I need is to group all the "Especies" that have a "Superficie" lower than the 4th.