# Make counter in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and have working query which take user 3 images. I want to make a count an give every image a number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ... and want that query output

```
-number (count),
-id,
-image,
-date
```

my sql query :

```
function bar_images_first($user_id)
{   
    $sql = "SELECT id, image, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date FROM images WHERE user_id = 3 LIMIT 3";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $user_id);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Is it possible to do counter in query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by setting a SQL parameter as

```
SET @cnt := 0;
SELECT
    @cnt := @cnt + 1,
    id,
    image,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date 
FROM images WHERE user_id = 3 LIMIT 3";
```

But such multiple statements cannot be executed from the PHP's `mysql_query()` method. But, mysqli function like `mysqli_multi_query()` does allow to execute multiple queries too, so *if possible use mysqli method rather than the AR methods.*

However, you can run multiple sets of query one by one.

```
$query = array(
    "SET @cnt := 0;",
    "SELECT
        @cnt := @cnt + 1,
        id,
        image,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date 
    FROM images WHERE user_id = 3 LIMIT 3"
);

foreach($query as $qry) {
     $result= $this->db->query($qry);
     //.........
}
```

Comment: what do you mean two queries ?

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs, He means run each query one by one, as in my last example.

Comment: @max_, To denote its a SQL Parameter

Answer (score 2):

To run as a single query:

```
SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number, id, image, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date
FROM images
JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
WHERE user_id = 3
LIMIT 3
```

This is very specific to MySQL though. If you want more portable code I would recommend making your row counter in code instead.

**Edit** - forgot to give due credit: [MySQL - row number in recordset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285660/mysql-row-number-in-recordset)