# Generate serial number in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table: student_marks

```
marks
-----
  44
  55
  64
  98
  76
```

Expected output:

```
serial_number|marks
--------------------
  1          | 44
  2          | 55
  3          | 64
  4          | 98
  5          | 76
```

Using mysql user defined variables, it could be done using query:

```
 set  @a:=0;select @a:=@a+1 serial_number, marks from student_marks;
```

Is there any way to achieve this in msyql without using user defined variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - row number in recordset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285660/mysql-row-number-in-recordset)

Comment: Why don't you want to use user defined variables?

Comment: I have to use two queries, one for initializing the mysql variable to 0 and another the actual query. I was trying to avoid two queries here.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Based on your reasons for not wanting to use user defined variables as wanting to avoid having 2 queries, one for inializing and one to use it you could use the following:

```
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 serial_number, 
        marks 
FROM    student_marks,
        (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

Comment: I wonder, how this works without `AS`  keyword in SELECT statement?

Comment: @diEcho The [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) state **The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an identifier.** See this [working example without AS on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0705e4/1)

Comment: What if I want to loop through not just numbers but also all upper and lower case letters (i.e. creating a base 62 number sequence), and have it all left-padded with 0's? :D

Comment: I suggest use of an explicit **cross join** instead. i.e. `FROM student_marks CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;` so the intention is clear.

Comment: But it is not working if i will order any another column with desc and asc

Comment: The sequence will simply represent the order by clause that you use. If you need the results in a different order then you need to use a sub query with an order by to get the sequence, then the outer order by for the order that you need the results in. E.g. `SELECT Name, marks, serial_number FROM (SELECT ..... ORDER BY marks) As t ORDER BY Name;`  this would apply the sequence based on marks, but the set would be ordered by name.

Comment: @GarethD what if we have inner join query, then where to place this 2nd select?

Comment: @NullPointer You can also `INNER JOIN` to the query that initialises the variable, e.g. `SELECT @a:=@a+1 AS serial_number FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID INNER JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f155b4/1

Answer (score 11):

Best Answer to this question should be the following, the best practice

```
SET @count:=0;
SELECT  (@count:=@count+1) AS serial_number, 
        marks 
FROM    student_marks
```

Comment: Why did you reproduce the same answer as [the accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11096550/4074148) from 2012?

Comment: This is not same answer, moreover it quit faster than @GarethD's solution

Comment: Just bad wording: he should have either suggested it as an alternative, or cited his evidence for "best practice". No reason to get angry or excited.

Comment: This is not the best answer to the question, since the OP specifically wanted a solution that uses one statement, not two. Moreover, the OP has already posted this solution as part of the question. So while may be a better approach if you can use more than one statement, it is not the best answer to *this* question.

Comment: Note: This number won't be in sequence if you have ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

I had a table with a column(c5) has contain a number x, I need a sql expression that repeated the same row x numbers of times:

my table A contains:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
16  1   2   16  3
16  1   2   17  2 
16  1   2   18  1
```

and I need:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  n
16  1   2   16  3   1
16  1   2   16  3   2
16  1   2   16  3   3
16  1   2   17  2   1
16  1   2   17  2   2
16  1   2   18  1   1
```

I solved That with the expression:

```
SELECT
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, row_number AS n
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
        FROM
            tablea
        JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
        WHERE
            @curRow < (
                SELECT
                    max(field1)
                FROM
                    tablea
            )
    ) AS vwtable2
LEFT JOIN tablea d ON vwtable2.row_number <= tablea.field1;
```

Answer (score 1):

tested in mysql 5.6:

```
SELECT
    @a:=@a+1 as serial_number,
    student.* 
FROM
    student
join (SELECT @a:= 0) a
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `serial number` with this query :

```
set @counter=0;
SELECT  @counter:=@counter+1 as serial_number from <table_name>
```

output :

```
   |...............................|
   | serial_number  |   first_name |
   |...............................|
   |      1         |    mojtaba   |
   |      2         |    athena    |
   |      3         |     azin     |
   |      4         |     ava      |
   |      5         |    arash     |
   |...............................|
```

in addition if you want to use in `where`

```
set @counter=0;
select serial_number from (SELECT  @counter:=@counter+1 as serial_number 
from <table_name>) as tbl_counter where serial_number > 3
```

output :

```
   |...............................|
   | serial_number  |   first_name |
   |...............................|
   |      4         |     ava      |
   |      5         |    arash     |
   |...............................|
```

Answer (score 1):

I found simple way to generate serial number

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by '1') AS serial_number,customer_id from users;
```

Also it support pagination

Comment: simplest one, however it existed in 2022 (supported by mysql 8), did not exist in earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. But you could produce the serial_number in program side, not the database side.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. I have already generated serial number using mysql user defined variables as well. I was wondering if there are some alternate ways in mysql to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers seemed satisfactory as you would need to initialize the variable as null in a separate query.

So posting the below all encompassing solution:

```
SELECT ROUND(@a:=@a+1,0) sr_num, t.* from (select @a:=0) initvars, your_table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

**@a:=@a+1 serial_no,**

**CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a**

```
SELECT @a:=@a+1 serial_no, sc.id, sc.name, sc.address, c.country,s.state 
FROM oc_table1 sc CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a LEFT JOIN oc_table2 .......
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN sr_no INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;

This will even edit your main table in case you forgot to create a column for serial numbers.
You can also use this to add sr_no column to two different columns and easily join them (or create a new table using both of them).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you make it an auto-increment field?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: For simplicity of asking question, I created this table. Actually, I have to add a serial number to a result which I will get by joining two tables.

Answer (score -1):

No, unless you have a column which containes these numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Though very late for the answer, generating the sequential ids without having two queries and without using joins and without using sub query.

```
SELECT *, (@cnt := if(@cnt IS NULL, 0,  @cnt) + 1) AS id FROM table_name;
```

Cheers

Comment: When executed multiple times, the cnt doesnt reset to 0