# MySQL query to select results with auto increment as a new column added in the result

Tags: mysql

I have a student's table with the following fields:

```
student(student_id, student_name, student_avg)
```

I need to write a query in MySQL which will display the result as :

Serial no. => the result should also have a new column with serial number as `1,2,3,...,n` like an auto increment for each row in the result.

```
student_id
student_name
student_avg > 4
```

I don't want to alter my table in any way. All I have to do is write a query which will give me the above result. I hope I am clear.

Example data:

```
student_id         student_name      student_avg 
 1                    abc               2.5
 2                    xyz               4.1
 3                    def               4.2
```

Sample output after querying:

```
serial_no    student_id    student_name     student_avg
  1             2            xyz               4.1
  2             3            def               4.2
```

Comment: please paste ur table and sample out put

Comment: student_id  student_name  student_avg                                                                   1            abc          2.5                                          2            xyz          4.1                                              3            def          4.2                                          sample output                                                               serial_no student_id student_name student_avg                            1            2         xyz           4.1                              2            3         def           4.2

Comment: AFAIK there're window functions `rank() over(...)` and `row_number()`  etc. for mysql 8.0

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this on

```
SELECT  @s:=@s+1 serial_number,student_id,student_name,student_avg
FROM    students,
        (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
WHERE
student_avg > 4;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11096550/1423506

Comment: Found something similar before. There is one problem for me though: when I combine this with another `order by`, the incremental numbering is not sorted anymore, it's applied before the ordering apparently.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

```
SET @serial=0;
SELECT @serial := @serial+1 AS `serial_number`, `column_name` FROM `table_name`;
```

In your particular case:

```
SET @serial=0;

SELECT 
   @serial := @serial+1 AS `serial_number`, 
   `student_id`, 
   `student_name`, 
   `student_avg`
FROM 
   `students`
WHERE
   `student_avg` > 4;
```