# Adding an auto_increment serial_id as a new col to a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my query:

```
select * from a
JOIN B
ON
a.id=B.id
JOIN C
ON
B.id=C.id
```

How do I add one more col in the beginning called 'serial_id' which is auto incremental?

Ive seen examples here :[MySQL query to select results with auto increment as a new column added in the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861799/mysql-query-to-select-results-with-auto-increment-as-a-new-column-added-in-the-r)

But the solution doesn't work when i have joins in my select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
SELECT *
,@a:= @a +1 `serial_no`
 FROM a
JOIN B
ON
a.id=B.id
JOIN C
ON
B.id=C.id
JOIN (SELECT @a:=0) t
```

or

```
SELECT *
,@a:= @a +1 `serial_no`
 FROM a , (SELECT @a:=0) t
JOIN B
ON
a.id=B.id
JOIN C
ON
B.id=C.id
```