# How To generate id based on joining query result

Tags: php, mysql

I need to listing counting data and  based "rate" values joining two tables .

Rate Table

```
 id    rate    ratevale
 -------------------------    
  1     N        NA    
  2     D        DH    
  3     F        FA    
  4     L        LD
```

Claim Table

```
id  rate

1    N

2    N

3    N

4    F

5    N

6    D

7    D

8    F

9    L
```

I need list the result following like that

```
id  Generate

1   NA-40-001

2   NA-40-002

3   NA-40-003

4   FA-40-001

5   NA-40-004

6   DH-40-001

7   DH-40-002

8   FA-40-002

9   LD-40-001
```

I have worked query following

```
$query="select count(Claim.rate) as count,Rate.ratevale from Claim leftjoin Rate on Claim.rate=Rate.rate group by Claim.rate";
```

Its display the count of each "rate and ratevalue" like following

```
NA->4

FA->2

DH->2

LD->1
```

But i need to how to list data above format.

Comment: What are the `40` and `00x` values in your "Generate" column?

Comment: 40 is static value and 00x id need to generate

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code :

```
$query="SELECT COUNT( Claim.rate ) AS count, Rate.ratevale
FROM claim
LEFT JOIN rate ON Claim.rate = Rate.rate
GROUP BY Claim.rate" ;
```

With Order By

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT( claim.rate ) AS count, rate.ratevale
FROM claim
LEFT JOIN rate ON claim.rate = rate.rate
GROUP BY claim.rate
ORDER BY count DESC" ;
```

Comment: I need like "1   NA-40-001

2   NA-40-002

3   NA-40-003

4   FA-40-001

5   NA-40-004

6   DH-40-001

7   DH-40-002

8   FA-40-002

9   LD-40-001"

Comment: See this link:   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861799/mysql-query-to-select-results-with-auto-increment-as-a-new-column-added-in-the-r]

Answer (score 0):

With the tables

```
CREATE TABLE ctab (id int,rate varchar(1)); -- claims table
INSERT INTO ctab (id,rate) VALUES
    (1, 'N'),(2, 'N'),(3, 'N'),(4, 'F'),(5, 'N'),
    (6, 'D'),(7, 'D'),(8, 'F'),(9, 'L');

CREATE TABLE rtab(id int,rate varchar(1), ratevale varchar(2));
INSERT INTO rtab (id,rate,ratevale) VALUES  -- rates table
    (1, 'N', 'NA'),(2, 'D', 'DH'),(3, 'F', 'FA'),(4, 'L', 'LD');
```

we can do the following:

```
SELECT t.id, CONCAT(ratevale,'-40-',RIGHT(CAST(i+1000 as char(4)),3)) rval
FROM (
 SELECT CASE WHEN @r =rate THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:= 1 END i,
        CASE WHEN @r!=rate THEN @r:=rate ELSE @r     END r, 
 id id,rate rate 
 FROM (SELECT @i:=1,@r:='') v, ctab c 
 ORDER BY rate,id
) t 
INNER JOIN rtab r ON r.rate=t.rate
ORDER BY id
```

and we get:

```
| id |      rval |
|----|-----------|
|  1 | NA-40-001 |
|  2 | NA-40-002 |
|  3 | NA-40-003 |
|  4 | FA-40-001 |
|  5 | NA-40-004 |
|  6 | DH-40-001 |
|  7 | DH-40-002 |
|  8 | FA-40-002 |
|  9 | LD-40-001 |
```

Play around with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9e3e/15

The basic idea is that we list the claims table, ordered by `rate` and turn it into a derived table `t`.

Having initialised `@i` to `1` and `@r` to `''` in the derived table `v` we check whether `@r=rate` and

- if so, we increment `@i`.
- otherwise (`ELSE`) we reset `@i` to `1` and `@r` to `rate`. 
  This happens in the second `CASE` clause.

We end up with a sequence column `i` that starts counting for each value of `rate`. In the outer `SELECT` statement the derived table `t` is then joined to the rates table `rtab` and a different sorting order is applied.

**Please note:**

This solution can also be seen as an alternative solution to [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) . The above MySQL query in can easily be rewritten in MSSQL by applying `row_number() over (partition...)`, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9e3e/8