# Include a complex logic in a single MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I wanted to reduce the programming logic in a code that search hotels by using a single query.

Let say this is the database table. There are several contracts from a single hotel.
[image]  
I wanted to get all the raws that satisfy input number of rooms for max_adults 1(capacity 1) rooms, number of rooms for rooms for max_adults 2(capacity 2) rooms and number of rooms for rooms for max_adults 3(capacity 3) rooms.

eg:

```
Input : 
2 rooms of max_adults=1(capacity 1) 
1 rooms of max_adults=2(capacity 2) 
3 rooms of max_adults=3(capacity 3)
```

The rows that satisfy all the 3 conditions with the `same hotel id` must be output.

As in here the output must contain all the raws of `hotel 1 and hotel 2`

Since they are two separate results, an extra column is needed to show a generated result_id (kind of serial number as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861799/mysql-query-to-select-results-with-auto-increment-as-a-new-column-added-in-the-r) which must has duplicates acording to this problem).

I'm thinking lots of ways to do this, but nothing works well. Will this be possible to do in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT r1.HOTEL_ID, r1.MAX_ADULTS, r1.NO_OF_ROOMS,
    r2.MAX_ADULTS, r2.NO_OF_ROOMS,
    r3.MAX_ADULTS, r3.NO_OF_ROOMS,
FROM rooms AS r1
INNER JOIN rooms AS r2 ON r1.HOTEL_ID=r2.HOTEL_ID
INNER JOIN rooms AS r3 ON r1.HOTEL_ID=r3.HOTEL_ID
WHERE r1.MAX_ADULTS=1
AND r2.MAX_ADULTS=2
AND r3.MAX_ADULTS=3
```

You will have to add clauses to check the *input number of rooms* conditions.

The *generated result_id* would be `r1.HOTEL_ID`.

You would get a single row per hotel.

Comment: Your answer going to save my day. Thanks. This is a kind of answer I expected. There may be several search results for a single hotel. So the  hotel id can't be used as the generated id. How can it be done using the same query by enhancing it.

Comment: Oh I think since a single raw is a single result, If I can generate a normal serial id, It would be my result_id !