# Inner Join of 3 tables according to the request

Tags: mysql, join

This is an extension of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847350/include-a-complex-logic-in-a-single-mysql-query/31847624#31847624). I have a query of inner joining 3 tables. (Actually self joining of the same table).

```
SELECT r1.HOTEL_ID, 
  r1.MAX_ADULTS, r1.NO_OF_ROOMS,
  r2.MAX_ADULTS, r2.NO_OF_ROOMS,
  r3.MAX_ADULTS, r3.NO_OF_ROOMS,
FROM rooms AS r1
  INNER JOIN rooms AS r2 ON r1.HOTEL_ID=r2.HOTEL_ID
  INNER JOIN rooms AS r3 ON r1.HOTEL_ID=r3.HOTEL_ID
WHERE 
  r1.MAX_ADULTS=1
  AND r2.MAX_ADULTS=2
  AND r3.MAX_ADULTS=3
```

Now I don't want to join them all at every time. I want to join these 3 tables according to a input request by ignoring one or two joins at a time. Can it be done by changing this query itself. (If possible it's better)

 Or I have to do it by applying the logic in the code.

Comment: applying the logic in the code

Comment: Means there is no way to do it inside the query?

Comment: yes. i almost shure there is no way to do it inside the query

Comment: Thanks. This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify script conditional basis.

Comment: Means there is no way to do it inside the query?