# Record Position in the database table

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a database table like following

Table: **"user"**

```
    u_id  uname
    111  abc
    112  xyz
    113  pqr
    115  mno
```

I want to ask:

can I know the actual position of the particular record in the table?

***For example:***

**user** having *uname* '**mno**' and *u_id* '**115**' is having position **4th** in the database.

Comment: probably you are asking for the serial number of the corresponding row If you order them by u_id. right?

Comment: depends on your sort order and new entries. It is normally created on the fly as a rank with *variables* as they call them. But at the moment, your question is unclear.

Comment: Luckily, users are in sequential order, so yes. But rows in an RDBMS table have no order so really this question makes no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are asking for the serial number of the corresponding row If you order them by u_id ascending.

If so here's the query:

```
SELECT
    u_id,
    uname,
    @a := @a + 1 SL

FROM
    user,   (SELECT @a := 0) serial
ORDER BY u_id ASC
```

**Here's the sample output :**

[image]

**CAUTION:** You may get different position number if you sort them based on other field. Since your question gave me a hint that the data are ordered based on **u_id** ascending so this query suits.
Again if you want the position number of your data based on **uname** field (ascending) the query might look like following:

```
SELECT
    u_id,
    uname,
    @a := @a + 1 SL

FROM
    user,   (SELECT @a := 0) serial
ORDER BY uname ASC
```

And sample output would look like:

[image]

***N:B: Position of the records may also change if new records are inserted.***

Comment: Right now this is following the route of the primary index one hopes is in place. Best to improve the answer and mention ordering. In other words, your `SL` is dependent on the ordering, and never set in stone. So I would back away from that concept (or else I get your serial number next time thru).

Comment: would you please clarify? @Drew

Comment: There is no mention of cautionary words of how the `SL` changes as the data changes. And if other decisions (read: inserts) are performed using the above data, links and integrity can get messed up fast.

Comment: @Drew, I've added some cautionary words. Please let me know if it's okay.

Comment: Also note the use of the word `serial` to most people would designate a value that does not change. Unlike terminology like rank or position used by bekt that denotes change (like a report, or a game server ranking).

Answer (score 0):

Try this on

```
SELECT  @s:=@s+1 position,user.*
FROM user,
    (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
ORDER BY u_id ASC;
```

[MySQL query to select results with auto increment as a new column added in the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861799/mysql-query-to-select-results-with-auto-increment-as-a-new-column-added-in-the-r)

Answer (score 0):

**Database :** postgresql

```
select u_id, uname, row_number() OVER () as rnum from table1
```

**Note :**  If you want row number then use row_number function of postgresql, if you want exact row number then you have to add new field in your table like id (primary key, autoincrement)