# C#: DataTable getting only one row of the search result

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, datareader

I'm having a sudden and strange problem with `DataTable`. I'm using C# with MySQL database to develop a system, and I'm trying to export custom reports. The problem is that, somehow, my `DataTable` is getting only one result (I've tested my query on MySQL and should be something like 30 results on the xls file and the `DataTable`).
Strangely, these functions are used in other parts of the system to export other kinds of reports, and work perfectly. This is the select function that I'm using:

```
public DataTable selectBD(String tabela, String colunas) {
    var query = "SELECT " + colunas + " FROM " + tabela;
    var dt = new DataTable();

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + query + "\n\n");

    try
    {
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, bdConn)) {
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException) {
        return null;
    }
    bdConn.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    cpf_cnpj, nomeCliente, agenciaContrato, contaContrato, 
    regionalContrato, carteiraContrato, contratoContrato, 
    gcpjContrato, avalistaContrato, enderecoContrato, 
    telefoneContrato, dataChegadaContrato, dataFatoGerContrato,
    dataPrimeiraParcelaContrato, dataEmissaoContrato, valorPlanilhaDebitoContrato 
FROM 
    precadastro 
    INNER JOIN 
    contrato 
        ON precadastro.cpf_cnpj = contrato.FK_cpf_cnpj 
    LEFT JOIN faseprocessual 
        ON contrato.idContrato = faseprocessual.FK_idContrato
```

And that is the [result of the query on SQLyog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKuSc.png)

I've tested and the `DataTable` returned by the function only receive the one row, and it's not the first row of the MySQL results. Someone had this kind of problem before?

Comment: What's your connection string?

Comment: this: "Persist Security Info = False;Server = localhost;DataBase = absadvocacia;Uid = root;Pwd = '''';"

But besides that place, the connection with the database works perfectly. Login, insert, update, delete... Actually, I use even the same functions in other place (to export user monitoring report), and it works.

Comment: Did you try while (reader.Read())   { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataTable` load expects primary key from your data (supplied by `DataReader`) and tries to guess it from passed rows. Since there's no such key, `Load` method guesses it's the first column (`cpf_cnpj`). But, values in that column aren't unique so the each row gets overwritten by next one, and the result is just one row in your `DataTable`.
It's the issue that persist for years, and I'm not sure there's one solution to rule them all. :)

You can try:

- change query so that some unique values get into first column (unfortunately, I can't see something unique in your screenshot) or concatenate two or more values to get unique value.
- Prepare `DataTable` by yourself by creating columns (this mirroring structure of resultset) and then iterate through `DataReader` to copy data.
- add some autoincrement value in your query (or make temporary table with auto_increment column then fill that table)

Last suggestion could be something like this (I haven't worked much with mySql, so this is some suggestion i have googled :)):

```
SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 AS id,
    cpf_cnpj, nomeCliente, agenciaContrato, contaContrato, 
    regionalContrato, carteiraContrato, contratoContrato, 
    gcpjContrato, avalistaContrato, enderecoContrato, 
    telefoneContrato, dataChegadaContrato, dataFatoGerContrato,
    dataPrimeiraParcelaContrato, dataEmissaoContrato, valorPlanilhaDebitoContrato 
FROM 
    precadastro 
    INNER JOIN 
    contrato 
        ON precadastro.cpf_cnpj = contrato.FK_cpf_cnpj 
    LEFT JOIN faseprocessual 
        ON contrato.idContrato = faseprocessual.FK_idContrato
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i:= 0) AS i
```

here's [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094466/generate-serial-number-in-mysql-query/11096550#11096550) which uses auto number in query.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped me a lot. I've tried to add "@i:=@i+1 AS id" and "(SELECT @i:= 0) AS i" and it worked on MySQL console and SQLyog, but not on my C# code and Visual Studio query editor. I've search a little more and find out that problably it's because it realy can't be done - it seems that it is blocked to prevent SQL injection. But so I've looked again on my Data Base and I had the primary key of my table "contrato" (wich in this case will always be unique), so I take it and ignore it when generating the .xls file and worked just fine.
Thanks a lot man.