# how to manipulate record's ID order?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a group of list and get results in re-ordered number fashion.

e.g.

### ID name

1. jack
2. jack
3. paul
4. bob
5. bob
6. paul
7. bob

Say I select name='bob' thus got its ID numbers 4,5,7

Now I want the results to be

in this order 1, 2, 3 ...

instead of 4, 5, 7 ...

because it's bob's first second and third, etc...

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: This looks like you're wanting to discard the existing ID, and assign another number. If that's the case, what you probably need is [ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql).

Comment: @Erayd could you please elaborate? I'm curious as to why something looks simple as this is not so easy to do in mysql. Like you said, it's basically assigning the selected rows with incremented number starting from 1.

Comment: Which aspect confuses you? Note I'm drawing your attention to the accepted answer in that thread, not the question.

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate serial number in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094466/generate-serial-number-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Here mysql variables can do the work. Declare & initialize a variable `@a = 0`,  assign an incremented value and select in query. The query should look like:

```
SET @a = 0;
SELECT @a := @a + 1 AS id, name FROM table_name WHERE name = 'bob';
SET @a = 0;
```

In the end, again set value of `@a = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql 8 then you could use window function [`rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) and [common table expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax)

```
with ordered_data as (
  select *, 
  rank() over (partition by name order by id asc ) rnk
  from your_table
  order by rnk
)
select * from ordered_data where name = 'bob';
```

Or if you are using older release then you could use a correlated query to get the rank

```
select a.id,a.name,
    (select count(*) 
    from your_table 
     where name= a.name 
     and id <= a.id) rnk
from your_table a
where a.name = 'bob'
order by a.id;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8dAAFtwxg2u2tkvUTgMzTy/2)